# Hosting HTML+CSS+JS websites with Django rest framework backend

Tags: django, web, django-rest-framework, hosting, web-hosting

My backend APIs are hosted on Django rest framework and the for the frontend I have purchased a theme which is on HTML, CSS, Bootstrap, and Javascript, I wanted to know what would be the best practice to host this website in production, should I have two servers one for handling the static website and other for the backend or shall I integrate this with the backend. The theme is quite vast and would like to go with the first option, so I go with the first option then where should I host the website, and does it impact the performance?

I have already researched but could not find what would be the best practice in this situation, Let me know if any other details are required.

Answer (score 1):

If you're use API and frontend template, you don't necessarily need to host them on separate servers. You can do that on one server. It's just a matter of API calls

Comment: How do I serve these on Django, I mean I think I would be able to import static files without changing the syntax of HTML to the Django template for example change the import syntax, etc? Also, do I have to define routes in the backend for all pages?

Comment: Are u using the MDT or API architecture?

Comment: I want to use API(Microservices) architecture with JWT authentication for requests.

Comment: As a matter of fact, you can host them on one server but make sure the front end  files are in entry directory of the server. You can host the API on a subdomain..

Comment: I got this point, just one last question how does routing work in suck cases, I want the URL for the homepage to be xyz.com and not xyz.com/index.html, can you tell me how can this be done with an Nginx server?

Comment: Sorry for responding late. Can I see your how you did it?

Comment: I hosted static page on Nginx as you said so my URL for the homepage was fine like it was xyz.com but when I switched to any other page it stated showing the name of the HTML file say if the file is setting.html it showed xyz.com/settings.html, but I want it to show the routes, for example, xyz.com/settings/, so is it possible to achieve this just by using Nginx?